# Найти слово синоним c#

Tags: c#, консоль

Всем привет. Есть такая задача

> Дан текстовый файл содержащий на каждой строке два слова - синонимы.
> С использованием коллекции Dictionary написать программу,
> позволяющую искать синоним для введенного с клавиатуры слова.

Я так понимаю, что мне нужно читать построчно из файла, записать в массив, и из массива записывать в словарь. После этого я ввожу слово, оно сравнивается с ключом, и мне выдаётся синоним. При попытке разделить строчку с помощью метода Split и добавить 1 слово как ключ, второе, как значение, вылетает ошибка "не удаётся преобразовать string[] в string". Если после этого добавить .ToString() или сделать List<string[]>, то будет записано System.String[]. Как это сделать, либо я неправильно мыслю?

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        FileStream Stream1 = new FileStream("sinonims.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Stream1);
        string s;
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        while ((s = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            words.Add(s.Split(' ').Tostring());
        }
        r.Close();
        Stream1.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(words[0]);
        /*for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i+=2)
            dic.Add(words[i], words[i+1]);/*
```

Comment: А зачем вам промежуточный список? Добавляйте сразу результат `Split` в словарь. 0-й элемент результата `Split` будет ключом, а 1-й значением для словаря. Как-то так. `var kv = s.Split(' '); dic[kv[0]] = kv[1];`

Comment: Также не забудьте учесть то, что пользователь может ввести как первое слово из пары, так и второе.

Comment: `words.Add(s.Split(' ').Tostring());` - попробуйте вместо этого следующий код: `words.AddRange(s.Split(' '));`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Так то да, но зачем вообще нужен промежуточный список, о нём и в задании ничего не сказано же?

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] s = new string[] { "белый светлый", "чёрный тёмный" };
var a_ = s.ToList()
   .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Split(' ')[0], s.Split(' ')[1]))
   .SelectMany(s 
      => new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() 
      { 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Key, s.Value), 
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Value, s.Key) 
      })
   .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

Примеры запроса-ответа:
`a_["светлый"] //ответ: белый`
`a_["чёрный"] //ответ: тёмный`

Comment: `new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Key, s.Value)` в данном случае эквивалентно `s`

Comment: Да, но читаться будет хуже, не будет сразу понятно что происходит.